# How to use a DSN file in a C# application?

Tags: c#, odbc

This is my old code.

```
conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"DSN=dBase Files";
```

It throws an Error: (I think my old code might still work on 32 bit machines, but I am on 64 now)

```
"[Error] [IM002] [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
```

All my searches told me to use SysWow64/odbcad32.exe to create a .DSN file.  Now I created the DSN file, How can I modify this line,  `conn.ConnectionString = @"DSN=dBase Files";`,  to point to the .DSN file I saved on disk?

Comment: I know in a web application you can do it in the `Web.Config` under `<appSettings>`.  Are you trying to on a Windows Form Application?

Comment: @Greg I'm trying to do it with a WPF application

Comment: Can you modify this Registry Key with your ODBC Driver information? `HKLM\Software\ODBC\ODBC.INI\ODBC Data Sources` The driver should contain those key values.

Comment: ODBC Data Sources under Administrative Tools has both 32-bit as well as 64-bit versions. Try, one then the other. It's bound to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I recall, I had to set up the DSN in ODBC Data Sources under Administrative Tools, but that was around the turn of the century.

This might help: `FILEDSN=c:\myDsnFile.dsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=;`

So something like:

```
conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = @"FILEDSN=C:\path\to\dsn\file\here.dsn;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=;";
```

From [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn).

Comment: I didn't actually need that username, password stuff to get it to work.

Comment: Was that because the authentication information was already in the file DSN or because it wasn't required?